# Whitespaces don't count as characters in edits?

Tags: support, edits

Just a minute ago I wanted to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23455057/2266261) and fix the wrong indentation. It needed 12 whitespaces if you use 4 per one indent. However, when I tried to submit this edit, I was told that my edit needs to be 6 characters long. Why is that? Whitespaces don't count? I don't like adding silly nitpicks in my edit to reach the required minimum and as a Python enthusiast, looking at code with wrong indentation causes my eyes to bleed.

Comment: Probably only trailing whitespaces don't count.

Comment: A more pertinent question is, *"what would 12 extra spaces really add to that question?"*... it's perfectly understandable as it is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76891?lq=1 <- lots of discussion about this. Also *don't* fix indent in questions related to whitespace-sensitive languages. You (nearly) never really know when it's a formatting issue or part of the problem.

Comment: @Emissary it disallows users to copy/paste code for debugging because it causes an Indentation Error.

Comment: I just had the same problem, and had to add blank lines to submit the edit. For me this is a bug. I disagree with @Mat, you can often be sure, that it's not part of the problem, if the user askes a question which is not about the very first basics